# How to substring of a string in matlab array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a matlab cell array of size 20x1 elements. And all the elements are string like `'a12345.567'`.
I want to substitute part of the string (start to 9th index) of all the cells.
so that the element in matrix will be like `'a12345.3'`.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
M = { 'a12345.567'; 'b12345.567' }; %// you have 20 entries like these
MM = cellfun( @(x) [x(1:7),'3'], M, 'uni', 0 )
```

Resulting with

```
ans =
  a12345.3
  b12345.3
```

For a more advanced string replacement functionality in Matlab, you might want to explore [`strrep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html), and [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html).

Answer (score 0):

Another method that you can use is [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html).  Use regular expressions and find the positions of those numbers that appear after the `.` character, and replace them with whatever you wish.  In this case:

```
M = { 'a12345.567'; 'b12345.567' }; %// you have 20 entries like these - Taken from Shai
MM = regexprep(M, '\d+$', '3');

MM = 

    'a12345.3'
    'b12345.3'
```

[Regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is a framework that finds substrings within a larger string that match a particular pattern.  In our case, `\d` is the regular expression for a single digit (0-9).  The `+` character means that we want to find at least one or more digits chained together.  Finally the `$` character means that this pattern should appear **at the end** of the string.  In other words, we want to find a pattern in each string such that there is a number that appears at the end of the string.  `regexprep` will find these patterns if they exist, and replace them with whatever string you want.  In this case, we chose `3` as per your example.